# Query mysql para pegar dados de duas linhas e juntar em apenas uma

Tags: mysql

Olá, não estou conseguindo executar uma query no mysql. Tenho uma tabela que possui os seguintes campos:

```
numero | data       | descricao | norma
 001   | 2017-02-28 | Lapis     | NBR
 001   | 2017-02-28 | Lapis     | ISO
```

Como no exemplo acima, existem registros que possuem o mesmo numero, data e descricao, mas a norma é diferente, com isso a query retorna mais de uma linha como resultado.

Já tentei usar Distinct, group by mas não deu certo.

Como posso montar essa query para me retornar em uma única linha: o numero, 
 a data, a descricao que são iguais e juntar na mesma linha as duas normas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acho que o que você está procurando é por `group_concat`.

Você pode fazer um `select` dos campos que deseja exibir, com um `group_concat` no campo que você quer juntar, e agrupando pelos campos que sejam iguais.

Mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT `numero`, `data`, `descricao`,  group_concat(`norma`) as norma
FROM suatabela
GROUP BY `numero`, `data`, `descricao`
```

Comment: Funcionou certinho, muito obrigado!!!